# How to mock TopicManagementResposne in my test class

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am creating a topic from the server itself (Using Firebase cloud messaging), and it is working fine. Now when I try to unit test this class, I get a null pointer exception stating that the object of `TopicManagementResposne` is null, I am mocking this class like this `TopicManagementResposne response = mock.(TopicManagementResposne.class)`, but I am getting null pointer exception.

in my class, the `response` object is returned from firebasemessaging.subscribeToTopic() method.
I have mocked my Firebase messaging class in the same way and it works fine, but when I try to do the same with this it fails.

what could be the possible issue here, and how can I solve it.
I am expecting to test class my class using TopicManagementResponse object . but its is null

my class :

```
@PostMapping("/subscribeToTopic")    public int createTopic(@RequestBody Topic topic) throws IOException, FirebaseMessagingException {
 
        String platformID = topic.getPlatformId();
        //my internal method to get firebase messaging app 
       FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = 
       fcmInitializer.getFirebaseMessaging(platformID);       
       
         String topicName = topic.getTopicName();
 
         if (topicName == null || topicName.isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        }        
             TopicManagementResponse response = 
             firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic(topic.getToken(), topicName);
             return response.getSuccessCount();
 
    }
```

my Test class :

```
public void createTopic(){FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = mock(FirebaseMessaging.class);
    TopicManagementResponse response = mock(TopicManagementResponse.class);
    Topic topic = new Topic();
    topic.setToken("some token");
    topic.setTopic("some topic");
    
    when(firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic(topic.getToken(), topic.getTopic())).thenReturn(response);
    assertEquals(response.getSuccessCount, 1);

}
```

Comment: Code snippet looks ok (accept `response.getSuccessCount` should be `response.getSuccessCount()`) - there must be some missing context.  Please update the question with the complete test class.  BTW, I would expect `response.getSuccessCount()` to return 0 (not 1) since it's mocked.